# How to use a C# task in an F# Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#, c#-to-f#

I wanted to learn some F# so I decided to create a Xamarin.Forms app with it, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with asynchronous and functional programming in F#. I'm using Xam.Plugins.Media C# library to try and take a photo but `CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync()` doesn't behave the same as if I was using it in C#.

Here's what I have in F#:

```ml
    type MainPage() =
        inherit ContentPage()
        let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<MainPage>)

        let viewModel = base.BindingContext :?> MainViewModel
        let checkNull (x : 'T) =
            match x with 
            | null -> raise (NullReferenceException(String.Format("{0} is null", x)))
            | _ -> x

        member this.TakePhoto(sender : obj, e : EventArgs) =
            if not CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || not CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported then
                raise (Exception("Camera not supported"))
            else 
                let mediaOptions = 
                    Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions(
                        Directory = "Test",
                        SaveToAlbum = true,
                        CompressionQuality = 75,
                        CustomPhotoSize = 50,
                        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                        MaxWidthHeight = Nullable(2000),
                        DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front)
                let file = CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
                viewModel.Stream <- (checkNull file).GetStream()
```

Here's the C# equivalent:

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
     if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        return;

     var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
     {
        Directory = "Test",
        SaveToAlbum = true,
        CompressionQuality = 75,
        CustomPhotoSize = 50,
        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
        MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
        DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front
     });

     if (file == null)
        return;

     viewModel.Stream = file.GetStream();
};
```

I know I'm not using F# in a fully functional aspect, but what am I missing to get it working or is there some limitation I'm unaware of when using a C# task in F#?

I tried using `async {}` expression, which did nothing on button click, but I assume that's putting `TakePhotoAsync` onto a background thread when it probably has to be run on the main thread. What I have now seemed to halfway work by showing the permission dialog and eventually showing a black screen like the camera is starting, but it gets stuck there and never actually shows the camera feed.

Comment: Perhaps you will get answers if you don't associate this question with Xamarin and C# in any way. Tasks are not C# specific - they are used in F# too. Your question does not appear to be very Xamarin specific.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue here is that you're using `RunSynchronously` to take a photo which is probably not doing what you expect it to. You can think of `RunSynchronously` to be like calling `.Result` on a .Net task object. So as a guess, this is leading to a deadlock somewhere in the Xamarin standard library.

Instead if you want your F# code to more closely resemble your C# code then you'll want something like the following:

```
member this.TakePhoto(sender: obj, e : EventArgs) =
    async {
       if not CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable ... then return ()
       else
           let! file = CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions(
               Directory = "Test",
               SaveToAlbum = true,
               CompressionQuality = 75,
               CustomPhotoSize = 50,
               PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
               MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
               DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front)) |> Async.AwaitTask

           if isNull file then return ()
           else
               viewModel.Stream <- file.GetStream()
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

The async block could also be replaced with a task computation expression as well if you were willing to take a dependency on an external library

Comment: That behaves just like the `async {}` set up I tried earlier or when I tried using `FSharp.Control.Tasks.V2.task {}`, which neither do anything on button click. The only way I was able to even get the permission dialog to prompt was by using `Async.RunSynchronously`, which get stuck at the same point as if I switched the C# version to use `Wait` and `Result`, so I take it `async {}` in F#, is not 100% equivalent to C# `await`

Comment: Could you update your question to show how your ```TakePhoto``` method is called? It looks like your C# method is a button click event handler, but your F# method isn't called from anything I can see there

Comment: The button click event is being set in Xaml on F# side